# Table is going out of container in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho-cde

I am trying to put table in container inwith Pentaho BI.Table is going out of container.How can i get rid of it?Is there any property for Table component to adjust its width,or columns width individiually?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: Which code you want to see? @SuperBiasedMan

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to style up the table. There is a property - `table-layout` - that can do the trick. For example:

```css
.dataTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Another option is to use the **Table Component** properties to set up the widths of the columns manually. You can use any CSS-valid values, including pixels and percentages.